# Passing value to a function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

No need to look anymore, I found the mistakse but I can't answer myself before eight hours because I have to few points.

I want to pass a pointer (It's declared inside a Window class and is valued inside its constructor) value reference to the function "fillBorderVertexes" which is declared inside the class function "Draw" but the compiler throws me this error:

```
1>window.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl fillBorderVertexes(class TransparentMaze *,class std::vector<class std::vector<float,class std::allocator<float> >,class std::allocator<class std::vector<float,class std::allocator<float> > > > *,float,float,int)" (?fillBorderVertexes@@YAXPAVTransparentMaze@@PAV?$vector@V?$vector@MV?$allocator@M@std@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$vector@MV?$allocator@M@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@MMH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Window::draw(void)" (?draw@Window@@UAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\VC++\PacMan\Debug\PacMan.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Is it related with something like that, that the pointer value or some parts of it are not seeable inside this function?

```
void Window::draw() {
::glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);   // Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
::glLoadIdentity();

void fillBorderVertexes(TransparentMaze*, vector<vector<GLfloat>>*, GLfloat, GLfloat, int);
void fillMazeVertexes(vector<vector<GLfloat>>*, Room*, GLfloat, GLfloat, int);
void drawMaze(vector<vector<GLfloat>>*, GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat);

static vector<vector<GLfloat>> borderVertexes;
static vector<vector<GLfloat>> mazeVertexes;
static bool done = false;

std::map<Point, Room*, compare>::iterator it = maze->getMaze().begin();

GLfloat x = ((GLfloat)it->first.getX() - 0.5f) * (room + border) - ((GLfloat)maze->getWidth() / 2.0f * (room + border));
GLfloat y = ((GLfloat)maze->getHeight() / 2.0f * (room + border)) - ((GLfloat)it->first.getY() - 0.5f) * (room + border);

if (!done) {
    // The problem is in this function with the first variable
    fillBorderVertexes(&*maze, &borderVertexes, room, border, ANGULAR_CORNERS);

    fillMazeVertexes(&mazeVertexes, &*it->second, room, border, ANGULAR_CORNERS);
    done = true;
}

drawMaze(&mazeVertexes, x, y, imageW, imageH, imageD);

::SwapBuffers(hdc);
}
```

Comment: That's not a compiler error, it's a linker error.

Comment: why `&*maze` and not just `maze` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the definition of the `fillBorderVertexes()` function exactly matches the declaration. For example, if the following was the definition:

```
void fillBorderVertexes(TransparentMaze, vector<vector<GLfloat>>*, GLfloat, GLfloat, int)
{
}
```

The linker would produce the error it is as the first parameter is defined as a `TransparentMaze*` in the declaration but as `TransparentMaze` in the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe that the compiler is unable to find the definition of the function fillBorderVertexes. Does the .cpp file where the implementation exist in the project?

Comment: The function prototype is at the beginning of the "draw" function and the implementation is after that function, function itself does right now nothing because I can't pass the first parameter "&*maze".